# How to parse JSON string into Map?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Java.

I have a JSON string like this given below :

```
{  
    "4562": {  
        "a":       "foo1",   
        "b":      "56",   
        "c":    "1342" 
    },
    "4563": {  
        "a":       "foo2",   
        "b":      "57",   
        "c":    "1343" 
    }
}
```

I want to store all the data from the JSON string into Map.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use Jackson Library** (`jackson-databind`).

Code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String inputJson = "{  \n" + 
                "    \"4562\": {  \n" + 
                "        \"a\":       \"foo1\",   \n" + 
                "        \"b\":      \"56\",   \n" + 
                "        \"c\":    \"1342\" \n" + 
                "    },\n" + 
                "    \"4563\": {  \n" + 
                "        \"a\":       \"foo2\",   \n" + 
                "        \"b\":      \"57\",   \n" + 
                "        \"c\":    \"1343\" \n" + 
                "    }\n" + 
                "}";
         Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = mapper.readValue(inputJson, Map.class);
         System.out.println(map);

    }

}
```

Output :

```
{4562={a=foo1, b=56, c=1342}, 4563={a=foo2, b=57, c=1343}}
```

**Download jar from here :** https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.1/

Comment: @preethamreddy Is this helpful ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply!, yes it is !!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
String json = ...;
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = gson.<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>fromJson(json, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this does what they want. With this, the values will be Strings, while from the JSON structure it seems that the values should be Maps. Granted, it's not very clear from the question which one is correct.

Comment: @a.deshpande012 you are right. It does appear to be a have map values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!, i think i found my answer